# parseInt and vars acting like strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

So Im trying to learn javascript - still pretty basic.

Im doing something like this

```
function add(amount) {
      // number is 9
     var number = parseInt($("#id").attr("number"));

     number = number + amount;
}
```

this makes the number a string - is there any way I can 'define' stuff so it knows its a integer so everything doesnt flood over in parseInts in all my functions?

Comment: Where is the line that calls `add()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `amount` value is a string then adding it to an `int` will result in concatenated text.

Either run `parseInt` on the `amount` before adding or make sure you are passing in an `int` value for `amount`.

**Update: Check for argument type before adding:**

```
function add(amount) {
    // number is 9
    var number = parseInt( $("#id").attr("number"), 10 );
    number = number + (typeof amount === "number" ? amount : parseInt( amount, 10 ) );
}
```

... and be sure to specify the `radix` parameter when using `parseInt`.

Comment: Just an fyi to OP... `number = number + typeof amount === "number" ? amount : parseInt( amount, 10 );` is a **[ternary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw.aspx)**... It's shorthand for an `if...else`. (would have confused me if I was just learning js)

Comment: Not sure it's actually needed to not `parseInt` a value that's already an integer.

Comment: @JanDvorak That's why the code checks for the `type` of the argument.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to use `parseInt` once: When getting the value from a place where you have a string. After that it's a number and will stay a number (unless you convert it back to a string).

However, **always** specify the second argument of `parseInt()`:

```
var number = parseInt($("#id").attr("number"), 10);
```

Otherwise it will use base 8 or 16 depending on the prefix which is something you usually do not want!

Additionally, HTML has no `number` attribute. Don't create custom attributes! Use `data-number="9"` in your HTML instead and access it using `.data('number')`. It even has the advantage that jQuery automatically guesses the type so you wouldn't need parseInt at all.

Comment: but it seems like it thinks the "amount" is a string by default - thats what annoys me

Comment: Well, that obviously depends on where it comes from. If you pass a string it's a string, if you pass a number it's a number.

Comment: +1 for "Always specify the [radix]" - this cannot be preached enough.

Comment: "It even has the advantage that jQuery automatically guesses the type so you wouldn't need parseInt at all." -- is there a way to disable that behavior, except by doing `.attr("data-number")`? I'm not sure it's an advantage.

Comment: No, that's actually what the docs suggest you to do. If I needed it more often I'd create `$.fn.rawData` though to do that while preserving the camelCase conversion (`fooBar` accesses the `data-foo-bar` attribute)

Comment: Does this mean i should always Json-encode my string data-attributes?

Comment: If you want to preserve whatever type you have (assuming it's not always just an alphanumeric string) it's a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to not calling `parseInt` everywhere in your code: Pre-process everything that you need to process as ints and save them using the `data` api from jquery (pseudocode):

```
$('.ints').each(function() { $(this).data("int", parseInt($(this).data("number"))); });
```

So, your code would become:

```
function add(amount) {
      // number is 9
     var number = parseInt($("#id").data("int"));
     number = number + amount;
}
```